# Node.js mysql module variables

Tags: mysql, node.js, express, module

I am having some issues with the [Mysql module](https://github.com/felixge/node-mysql). Basicly I want to insert a set of values into my database, I'm using the express framework. Here is my route:

```
router.post('/', function (req, res) {
var password = req.body.password;
var website = req.body.website;
var desc = req.body.desc;
var user = 'User';
var date = 2015;

var connection = mysql.createConnection({
    host: 'localhost',
    user: 'root',
    password: '',
    database: 'passwordmanager'
});
connection.connect();
var query = 'INSERT INTO passwords(password,description,user,date,website) VALUES('
password,desc,user,date,website
')';
connection.query(query);
connection.end();
res.redirect('/');
```

});

Thanks in advance. ;)

Comment: Do you know how to build a string? For example, concatenating the two strings `'Hello '` and `'World!'` together? Building a sql string is no different (though you'll want to escape them first to avoid sql injection)

Comment: Also, see the documentation: https://github.com/felixge/node-mysql#performing-queries (which is convenienty linked in your question)

Answer (score 0):

It looks like connection.query() is expecting a callback function as the second parameter.

See [the documentation introduction](https://github.com/felixge/node-mysql#introduction) for an example.

Answer (score 0):

So, I know now what was wrong, I just forgot the +.

So the correct version of the code would be:

```
var query = 'INSERT INTO passwords(password,description,user,date,website) VALUES('+password,desc,user,date,website+')';
```